# Windows is keeping large files I opened once in physical memory, in standby. How can I stop this?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, memory, memory-management

I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit, have 16gb of physical memory, and I understand why Windows wants to do this, but my specific case is really odd and annoying.

For some reason, on occasion, when I open a several GB file once - even if it's only once in the lifetime of the file and only for a few minutes, even if it's just a video file - it puts that file into "Standby (Physical) memory", putting my physical memory usage over 80% - sometimes over 90%. The worst part is, is that the file never gets removed automatically - I have to either restart, or use RAMMap to clear it out.

I understand why Windows manages memory the way it does, and that memory is meant to be used - however this is a bit of a problem for me since it never seems to clear these files out of standby on its own - and my performance suffers a significant amount as a result. I have an adequate page file on my SSD, my ram doesn't have any errors - my issue is just that Windows is predicting the wrong files I need to keep in physical memory, and not removing them after I close the file.

**Edit / Update:**

1. Superfetch *is* disabled and has been for months.
2. The pagefile is on an SSD.
3. Process Explorer, RamMap, and HWiNFO all point towards these one time short use meaningless files being in StandBy, not in active memory (As shown in RamMap).
4. When these files are removed from Standby - the physical memory usage goes down according to the tools listed above.
5. My system doesn't 'think' it needs ram, and that's the exact issue at hand - it **does** need ram, and it's not clearing out the files using Standby memory unless I do it manually. As I said above, my memory usage can get to over 90% and sluggish, and not remove files Windows only needed once in the entire life of the file - instead preferring to remove files still needed in memory.

**In summary:** Windows is keeping files it doesn't need in memory, and removing files it does need when it asks for more ram. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

I'm not sure who marked this as a duplicate question, but the linked "duplicate" has nothing to do with my issue.

Comment: What makes you think something's is wrong.  You should be able to replace that memory once you close the file,  it yes, Windows will keep it around until that happens

Comment: Superfetch is disabled, checked in multiple areas. So either you're wrong, or there's another issue here.

Comment: The linked Q&A does not answer this question. It should not be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> it puts that file into "Standby (Physical) memory", putting my physical memory usage over 80% - sometimes over 90%

Er but.. Standby does not count toward physical memory usage, whether it's used for the SuperFetch cache or not. Of course it counts toward memory *present*. But standby is not part of the "% used". Even though that file is cached into it that memory it is instantly discardable, remaining just as "Available" for something else as it was if it had never been used for anything.

> The worst part is, is that the file never gets removed automatically - I have to either restart, or use RAMMap to clear it out.

Then your system thinks it doesn't need the RAM.

> I have an adequate page file on my SSD

Something's odd here. The caching of files into the standby list is done by SuperFetch. But SuperFetch is normally disabled on a system with an SSD for the OS disk. Did you re-enable it?

Comment: "Er but.. Standby does not count toward physical memory usage," - Process Explorer, HWiNFO, and RAMMap disagree with you - or something is really bugged on my end, because the files are in standby and are counting towards my physical memory. My system DOES need ram, and it's removing stuff other than the massive file(s), causing the slow down - which is the problem and causing performance issues. Superfetch is disabled too - I made sure of that before posting here and again just now.

Comment: I don't know what you're looking at specifically, but you must be misinterpreting something. What Windows considers "Available" , i.e. not "In use", is the sum of Standby, Free, and Zeroed. Sure, Standby is counted as part of the total RAM on the system in e.g. RAMmap but that doesn't mean it's part of "in use". Rather, it is part of "available", just as Free and Zeroed are, because it does not contain anything that must be saved to disk before use. Cached file contents can always be dumped immediately because if needed they can be read again from the same file at any time later.

Comment: p.s. - after a reboot, do the same "problem" files show up in the cache? or do they not appear in the cache until you use them? What program are you using to access these files, e.g. what media player? finally, can you post a screenshot of something that specifically shows one of these massive cached files in Standby RAM? And of something that shows signs that your system is short on RAM, like a high hard pagefault rate?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such way of preventing windows from caching them. Windows still cache items manually opened by the user and the necessary system files as well. The work of the **superfetch(*sysmain*)** service is to preload files and other items according to the usage patterns of the user during previous boots. If you opened a certain file during previous boot, superfetch precaches those files with the **frequent access mechanism** (that is, with the intension that you're likely to re-access after next boot. Those **stand-by files** only assigns-to, a percentage amount of the memory that will be needed when you open the file again. It is not active in the usage % and will be discarded with immediate effect when more ram is needed by a **active-working-set** process(a running process that is currently allocating part of the available ram) for itself.